# How do I pass an enumeration on a base class, to the constructor of a subclass

Tags: c++, enums

I have the following base class defined:

```
class CDeviceClientRequest
{
public:
   /** Enumeration for the client message identifier. */
   enum EClientMessageIdentifier
   {
      TS_SET_ACTIVE,      // Set Active request for Total Station device.
      GPS_SET_ACTIVE,     // Set Active request for GPS device.
      TS_SET_COM_PORT,    // Set COM Port request for Total Station device.
      GPS_SET_COM_PORT,   // Set COM Port request for GPS device.
      TS_GET_OBSERVATION, // Get Observation request for Total Station device.
      GPS_GET_POSITION,   // Get Position request for GPS device.
      GPS_GET_QUALITY     // Get Quality request for GPS device.
   }; // EClientMessageIdentifier

   /**
    * Getter method for the client message identifier.
    */
   EClientMessageIdentifier getMessageId();

protected:
   /**
    * Protected constructor.
    *
    * @param messageId
    *           The enumeration representing the request message identifier.
    */
   CDeviceClientRequest(EClientMessageIdentifier messageId) 
       : m_iMessageId(messageId) {}

private:
   /** The enumeration representing the request message identifier. */
   EClientMessageIdentifier m_iMessageId;
}; // CDeviceClientRequest
```

This has the following sub-class:

```
class CDeviceSetActiveRequest : CDeviceClientRequest
{
public:
   /**
    * Getter method for the activation flag.
    */
   bool getActiveFlag();

protected:
   /**
    * Protected constructor.
    *
    * @param messageId
    *           The enumeration representing the request message identifier.
    * @param setActive
    *           The flag for the activation request.
    */
   CDeviceSetActiveRequest(EClientMessageIdentifier messageId,
                           bool                     setActive)
       : CDeviceClientRequest(messageId), 
         m_bActive(setActive) {}

private:
   /** Flag for the activation request. */
   bool m_bActive;
}; // CDeviceSetActiveRequest
```

Which also has the following instantiable sub-class:

```
class CDeviceTSSetActiveRequest : CDeviceSetActiveRequest
{
public:
   /**
    * Public constructor.
    *
    * @param setActive
    *           The flag for the activation request.
    */
   CDeviceTSSetActiveRequest(bool setActive) 
       : CDeviceSetActiveRequest(CDeviceClientRequest::TS_SET_ACTIVE, 
                                 setActive) {}
}; // CDeviceTSSetActiveRequest
```

So you create an object of type CDeviceTSSetActiveRequest passing in a boolean parameter.
It invokes the superclass CDeviceSetActiveRequest constructor, passing in the enumeration value for the type of request.
It finally invokes the CDeviceClientRequest setting the enumeration value on the private member variable.

However the code refuses to compile giving the following error message:

```
camd011> make
g++ -c CDeviceTSSetActiveRequest.cpp \
        -I.. -o bin/CDeviceTSSetActiveRequest.o
In file included from CDeviceTSSetActiveRequest.cpp:13:0:
CDeviceClientRequest.h: In constructor 'device::request::CDeviceTSSetActiveRequest::CDeviceTSSetActiveRequest(bool)':
CDeviceClientRequest.h:30:1: error: 'class device::request::CDeviceClientRequest device::request::CDeviceClientRequest::CDeviceClientRequest' is inaccessible
CDeviceTSSetActiveRequest.h:37:34: error: within this context
make: *** [bin/CDeviceTSSetActiveRequest.o] Error 1
```

Can anyone help? How do I use the enumeration defined in my main baseclass, in the instantiable subclass?

Forgot to add: The cpp versions of the files implement the getter methods.

- CDeviceClientRequest::getMessageId() in CDeviceClientRequest.cpp
- CDeviceSetActiveRequest::getActivFlag() in CDeviceSetActiveRequest.cpp
- CDeviceTSSetActiveRequest.cpp is empty and just includes the header.

The above 2 cpp files, with getter methods, compile without any problem. It is only the 3rd where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use public inheritance, like this:

```
class CDeviceSetActiveRequest : public CDeviceClientRequest
/* ... */
class CDeviceTSSetActiveRequest : public CDeviceSetActiveRequest
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're privately inheriting your classes, so the middle class hides away the enumeration.

You probably want public inheritance here: `class CDeviceSetActiveRequest : public CDeviceClientRequest` and `class CDeviceTSSetActiveRequest : public CDeviceSetActiveRequest` (notice I added the word public in there).